# Pass model to child component

Tags: java, wicket

Let's say I have the following setup.

```
public class TextPanel extends Panel {

    public TextPanel(String id) {
        this(id, null);
    }

    public TextPanel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
        super(id, model);
        add(new Label("text", model));
    }
}
```

What is the best way to keep the model of the label up-to date. There are two ways I can think of but I am not sure if there are any draw backs or better ways.

Overriding `onModelChanged` and call `get("text").setDefaultModel(getDefaultModel())` or implementing a (new?) model.

```
public class DefaultComponentModel implements IModel<Object> {

    private final Component component;

    public DefaultComponentModel(Component component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject() {
        return component.getDefaultModelObject();
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        component.setDefaultModelObject(object);
    }
}
```

And use it for the label. (`new Label("text", new DefaultComponentModel(this))`)

Important is that the solution should work when the defaultModel of a component changes or a CompoundPropertyModel is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replace `this(id, null);` with `this(id, Model.of(""));`. This way you can update the TextPanel's model object (e.g. `textPanel.setModelObject("new text")`) and this will automatically update the Label.

If you set a new model (i.e. `textPanel.setModel(newModel)` then you will have to override TextPanel#setModel() method and call `get("text").setModel(newModel)` too.

Comment: Somehow I always thought that `setDefaultModel(model)` is final. But now that I know that it is not final just overriding it seems like the best approach. Only downside is, that CompoundPropertyModel doesn't work.